# Getting 1215 error 'Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Can anyone see from my code why I'm getting this error? This is new to me so still learning. Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE DIRECTOR(
DIRECTOR_ID VARCHAR (6) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
F_NAME VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
L_NAME VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE TITLE_DIRECTOR(
TITLE_ID VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
DIRECTOR_ID VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL,
TITLE_NAME VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
DIRECTOR_FNAME VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
DIRECTOR_LNAME VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
INDEX (DIRECTOR_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (DIRECTOR_ID) REFERENCES DIRECTOR (DIRECTOR_ID));
```

Comment: This works perfectly on my MySQL installation. Is this the exact code you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have MyISAM as default engine, just put the implicit engine to InnoDB:

```
CREATE TABLE DIRECTOR(
  DIRECTOR_ID VARCHAR (6) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  F_NAME VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
  L_NAME VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;



CREATE TABLE TITLE_DIRECTOR(
  TITLE_ID VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
  DIRECTOR_ID VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL,
  TITLE_NAME VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  DIRECTOR_FNAME VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
  DIRECTOR_LNAME VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
  INDEX (DIRECTOR_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (DIRECTOR_ID) REFERENCES DIRECTOR (DIRECTOR_ID)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;;
```